# Adding a service provider with Kerberos - WSO2 IS 5.1

Tags: wso2, kerberos, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to add a service provider in the Identity Server 5.1 .

The problem is that when I try to configure an authentication with Kerberos, I have to create the service principal. When I am creating the password for that service I always get this error msg:

Password does not meet system requirements. Must be at least 6 characters long.

I tried a lot of passwd's but always get this message.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the code of IS 5.1.0. Checked the code and this( **[\\\\S]{5,30}** )[1] is the default regex used to validate the password. I tried a password like "SSSSSS" and worked :).

BTW this is fixed in IS 5.2.0. You can try out the WSO2 Identity Server 5.2.0-beta2 from [2]

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/directory-server-manager/org.wso2.carbon.directory.server.manager/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/directory/server/manager/internal/LDAPServerManagerConstants.java#L29

[2] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/download/v5.2.0-beta2/wso2is-5.2.0-beta2.zip

Comment: Do you think that I will be able to reproduce this example on the latest stable version of identity server and enterprise service bus? http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/07/kerberos-authentication-using-wso2-products/

Comment: I think you should be able to do this. Try it out and if you come across any issues drop a mail to dev@wso2.org will help you out.

Comment: Already sent an email. The ESB hasn't got an option to securize the echo service. Do you know something about that?Sent the email a week ago but no answer. Thanks in advance.